# How to make dynamic table save into Database SQL Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I do have Dynamic table but only for client side and I've try to make it save into database SQL Server. But i couldn't save into database. So, you guys have any logic to make these `javascript` save into database.

```js
function add_row(data_table) {
  // make a new row 
  var new_Component = document.getElementById("new_Component").value;
  var new_KRA = document.getElementById("new_KRA").value;
  var new_KPI = document.getElementById("new_KPI").value;
  var new_SFA = document.getElementById("new_SFA").value;
  var new_Target = document.getElementById("new_Target").value;
  var new_Weightage = document.getElementById("new_Weightage").value;


  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if (rowCount >= 15) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You have reached the maximum. 12 only !"; // Message alert 
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
    }, 5000); // Message alert will dissaper after 5 second  // 5000 equal to 5 seconds

    return false;
  }

  //add row button
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'> \
 <td id='Component_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_Component + "</td> \
 <td id='KRA_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_KRA + "</td> \
 <td id='KPI_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_KPI + "</td> \
 <td id='SFA_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_SFA + "</td> \
 <td id='Target_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_Target + "</td> \
 <td id='Weightage_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_Weightage + "</td> \
 <td> \
 <input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> \
 <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> \
 <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'> \
 </td> \
 </tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_Component").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_KRA").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_KPI").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_SFA").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_Target").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_Weightage").value = "";

}


function delete_row(no) //delete function 
{
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
}

function edit_row(no) // edit function // HOW TO ADJUST THIS FUNCTION INTO ADD FUNCTION 
{
  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "block";

  var Component = document.getElementById("Component_row" + no);
  var KRA = document.getElementById("KRA_row" + no);
  var KPI = document.getElementById("KPI_row" + no);
  var SFA = document.getElementById("SFA_row" + no);
  var Target = document.getElementById("Target_row" + no);
  var Weightage = document.getElementById("Weightage_row" + no);

  var Component_data = Component.innerHTML;
  var KRA_data = KRA.innerHTML;
  var KPI_data = KPI.innerHTML;
  var SFA_data = SFA.innerHTML;
  var Target_data = Target.innerHTML;
  var Weightage_data = Weightage.innerHTML;

  Component.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Component_text" + no + "' name='Component_text" + no + "' value='" + Component_data + "'>";
  KRA.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='KRA_text" + no + "' name='KRA_text" + no + "' value='" + KRA_data + "'>";
  KPI.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='KPI_text" + no + "' name='KPI_text" + no + "' value='" + KPI_data + "'>";
  SFA.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='SFA_text" + no + "' name='SFA_text" + no + "' value='" + SFA_data + "'>";
  Target.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Target_text" + no + "' name='Target_text" + no + "' value='" + Target_data + "'>";
  Weightage.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Weightage_text" + no + "' id='Weightage_text" + no + "' value='" + Weightage_data + "'>";
}

function save_row(no) // save function
{
  var Component_val = document.getElementById("Component_text" + no).value;
  var KRA_val = document.getElementById("KRA_text" + no).value;
  var KPI_val = document.getElementById("KPI_text" + no).value;
  var SFA_val = document.getElementById("SFA_text" + no).value;
  var Target_val = document.getElementById("Target_text" + no).value;
  var Weightage_val = document.getElementById("Weightage_text" + no).value;

  document.getElementById("Component_row" + no).innerHTML = Component_val;
  document.getElementById("KRA_row" + no).innerHTML = KRA_val;
  document.getElementById("KPI_row" + no).innerHTML = KPI_val;
  document.getElementById("SFA_row" + no).innerHTML = SFA_val;
  document.getElementById("Target_row" + no).innerHTML = Target_val;
  document.getElementById("Weightage_row" + no).innerHTML = Weightage_val;

  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Create a layout of Section B - KPI Planning</title>
  <style>
    body {}
    
    p {
      font-family: Calibri;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    select {
      font-family: Calibri;
    }
    
    table {
      width: 80%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      font-family: Calibri;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    tr,
    td {
      border: solid black 1px;
      align: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    input {
      width: 100%;
      font-family: calibri;
    }
    
    textarea {
      font-family: Calibri;
      width: auto;
    }
    
    .button {
      width: 8%
    }
    
    .success {
      background-color: #ddffdd;
      border-left: 5px solid #4CAF50;
    }
    
    .limit {
      background-color: #FFCACA;
      border-left: 5px solid #FF0000;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function savebtn() {
      document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "Data insert successfully!"; // this message will display as Alert !!
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "";
      }, 5000); // this function will make the message alert will dissapear
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <br>


  <!--- Javascript Alert messages : success --->
  <p class="success" align="center" style="font-weight:bold" id="alert"></p>
  <!--- Javascript Alert messages : success --->

  <!--- Javascript Alert messages : error --->
  <p class="limit" align="center" style="font-weight:bold" id="error"></p>
  <!--- Javascript Alert messages : error --->

  <table id="data_table">

    <form action="" method="post">

      <!--- Row Title --->
      <tr style="color:White;" bgcolor="#0C457F">
        <td>Component</td>
        <td>KRA</td>
        <td>KPI</td>
        <td bgcolor="black">SFA</td>
        <td>Target</td>
        <td bgcolor="black">Weightage %</td>
      </tr>
      <!--- Row Title end --->



      <!--- Add new row --->
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_Component"></input>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_KRA"></input>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_KPI"></input>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_SFA"></input>
        </td>
        <!--- How to make dropdown --->
        <td><input type="text" id="new_Target"></input>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_Weightage"></input>
        </td>
        <!--- How to make dropdown --->

        <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" class="add" onClick="add_row('data_table')" /></td>
      </tr>

      <p></p>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
        <td>GRAND TOTAL : 100%</td>
      </tr>

      <!--- Add new row end --->

  </table>
  <p align="center">
    <input class="button" type="Submit" value="Save" onclick="savebtn()">
  </p>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: JS cant't save to a database located at your server, you need server-side code for that task. Send the needed data with AJAX to your server, and save the send data as you need.

Comment: You need some kind of backend. The JavaScript runs in the browser and usually doesn't have access to the database. At least not if the database doesn't provide some kind of http interface. And SQL Server doesn't provide something like this.

Comment: Here is an idea on how to create such a backend: https://vooban.com/en/tips-articles-geek-stuff/how-to-quickly-create-a-simple-rest-api-for-sql-server-database/

Comment: Anyone who has a complete example using dynamic table and can record data into mysql ?